# Firefox console.log preventing JavaScript String from getting garbage collected?

Tags: javascript, string, firefox, garbage-collection

With the following code whenever console.log is enabled the String referenced by o.big will not get garbage collected. As soon as I remove the logging statement the memory for the big String gets freed after the execution of the handler function finishes.

I am using Firefox 9.0.1 and the memory profiling was done with about:memory.

```
$(function() {  
    var handler = function() {  
      var o = {};  
      o.big = (new Array(20*1024*1024)).join("x");  
      console.log(o.big);  
      delete o.big;  
    };  

    $("#btn").click(handler);
});
```

I am fairly new to JavaScript and it would be great if someone could point out to me why the String does not get marked by gc if used within console.log.

Comment: do you clear the firebug console manually or by calling `console.clear()` ? If not, I have an idea where the memory gets lost..

Comment: @jAndy: Adding console.clear() or clearing the console manually doesn't seem to make a difference. I am just using firefox web console at the moment. The memory allocation is still showing up as "40.07 MB (33.74%) -- string-chars" in about:memory.". I was also triggering a gc sweep manually via the about:memory UI.

Comment: Not 100% sure but I think the `console` uses `eval` to do it's work. Therefore the variable will be put into a global object and will therefore never be eligible for GC.

Answer (score 2):

Although I'm not too familiar with Firefox's / Firebug's handling of `console.log()` I assume that the console showing the "logged" object provides a way of examining and interacting with it. This is at least the case for Chrome.

Therefore, the console needs a reference to the object which will be kept in memory and cannot be garbage collected until the console releases the reference (which may not happen until the page hosting the script is reloaded).

Finally, keep in mind that there is no explicit relationship between the [`delete` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) and garbage collection.

Comment: This would makes sense to me. It sounds like quite a big thing to watch out for if console.log can affect the garbage collection in such a negative way (I always worried about speed, never memory when it came to logging). Strange that this is not more widely discussed.

Comment: @mzu You'll find that the majority of JavaScript developers don't write large enough web apps to run into any issues here. Once the page is unloaded, the browser should clean up just fine. Also, some of the performance optimization efforts going on are ridiculous, since they target the wrong side of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if Firefox keeps a reference to the original string there. I'd argue that `console.log()` retains a *copy*, since strings are first-class members in JS.

You can see the `string-chars` memory usage dropping in `about:memory`, but `heap-unclassified` rising. This may be related to https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=563700, or it may mean that FF's GC is broken.

Comment: Hm, the memory allocated for string-chars stays pretty much constant at about 40MB in my case. There is an initial shift to heap-unclassified though. So the 40MB might as well be a copy within console while the original String gets cleaned up.